# How do you create opaque liquid?

Tags: materials, color

I am following along with a beginners tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdWUjEMzDhg) that creates a clear glass mug with coffee in it. I am attempting to make hot chocolate instead of coffee. I have the object selected and am attempting to change the material as per the instructions. Changing the density under absorption volume only makes it darker. It does not change the opacity. What should I change to make it appear more solid and like hot chocolate rather than dirty lake water?

Answer (score 4):

For materials such as milk, latte or hot chocolate, the use of `Subsurface Scattering` is a good choice. It allows the light to enter the solid material, scatter around, and exit at another point. The material is not transparent but still opaque.

The liquid in the following example has a subsurface scattering of 0.055, base color and subsurface color are the same (hex: 835842), Subsurface Radius is (1.0, 0.75, 0.5), no transmission (glass), unchanged alpha (1.0=no transparency).

The `Bump map` is from the tutorial video "How to Make Milk in Blender EEVEE" (https://youtu.be/Hzpmz683xsw). It adds a very subtle distortion of the reflections on the surface.

[image: example]

Milk shader setup:
[image: node setup for milk]

Answer (score -5):

CYCLES select the mesh you want to be transparent.

Go to the Object header and check the Transparency box.

Go to the Material header, add a new material and decrease the Alpha value in the Settings panel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The mesh is currently transparent. I want it to not be transparent. 

Also, what version are you using? I do not see a Transparency box under the Object header.

Comment: I'm using 2.90..

Comment: We're using the same version but I can't follow your steps.